# Data enforcing in scheme

Tags: scheme

In my implementation below of vector and line segment, it seems weird the way that I'm using car and cdr in my implementation of seg-start and xcor. It seems too general, or is this the way loosely typed languages work? For example, I can't say get the xcor of just only a car of a vector.

```
(define make-vector cons)  // accept 2 numbers and make a vector.
(define make-segment make-vector) // 2 vectors connected to make a segment.

(define seg-start car) 
(define seg-end cdr) 

(define xcor car)
(define ycor cdr)

(define vector1 (make-vector 1 2))
(define vector2 (make-vector 3 4))

(define seg1 (make-segment vector1 vector2))
(xcor (seg-start seg1))
(ycor (seg-start seg1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Scheme implementation supports records (SRFI 9) or structs, it's often better to use that rather than just cons cells or vectors. (Though, records and structs usually use vectors behind the scenes, but that's an implementation detail.)

Answer (score 0):

If `make-vector` is defined:

```
  (define make-vector list)
```

and `make-segment`:

```
  (define make-segment list) ; don't redirect through `make-vector`
```

Then the accessors can be

```
  (define seg-start first)
  (define seg-end   second)
```

and

```
  (define xcor first)
  (define ycor second)
```

The advantage is that it becomes easy to extend the system and add a *z* coordinate or create a polygons or series of connected vectors without rewriting the code. Cons cells will reduce memory usage slightly, but if you're running out of RAM in an age of cheap gigabytes, it may be time to look at  rewriting critical sections in C.

Comment: Since George doesn't care how the data is represented you can start with `cons` and change it to `list` later. Using you defined accessors (`seq-end`) when making operations makes sure you only need to change the `make-obj`and affected accessor.

Comment: @Sylwester If the goal is really to have them linked then `(define my-special-constructor cons)` is probably a much better alias because it abstracts the commonality between the two functions rather than making an arbitrary dependency between the definition of `make-vector` and `make-segment`...that is which is the tweety-bird and which is the egg? And if the implementation switches to `struct`s then the constructors will be independent. Paint the boxes black early, I always say.

Comment: I agree to black box it. I just didn't understand why you change from `cons` to `list` since it's a implementation detail you can change if you have to. You only need to updtae your accessor to reflect the internal change and off you go.

Comment: @Sylwester I would use `list` because `cons` is maxed out as a data-structure, can fail over a wider range of bad data, and is a lower level abstraction. I might create a linked list data-structure for parallel code in another language. I doubt I would ever create a cons cell data structure in another language for this problem. This is a bit like looking, cons hammer in hand, at the data and seeing a nail. Two fields is not really a fundamental property of points and geometric collections of points. The problem domain should drive the datatype, not the data-structures of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cons`, `car` and `cdr` is not bad, but users of that interface might face weird errors when they try your interface on bad data. I usually start using simple objects this way and move on the second I need more. you can combine this with a tag to be able to make type checking. eg.

```
(define pair-tag (list 'pair))
(define (kons a d) (cons pair-tag (cons a d)))
(define (kons? x) (and (pair? x) (eq? (car x) pair-tag)))
(define (kar x) (if (kons? x) (cadr x) (error "not a kons")))
(define (kdr x) (if (kons? x) (cddr x) (error "not a kons")))
```

There are ways to make new types with [SRFI-9 Record types](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-9/srfi-9.html). You'll typically get type checking and the error messages gets better without having to do it yourself.

For a full object system and OO programming you can go for [TinyCLOS](https://github.com/dharmatech/clos).
Depending on your implementation that code might need some tweaking but I did get it working on Racket R6RS once (I think it runs out of the box for Ikarus)